# Enums in NHibernate from Existing Table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, enums, nhibernate-mapping

I have many tables in my schema design (legacy, cannot be changed) with the pattern:

```
Widget
-----------
WIDGET_ID (int, PK)
WIDGET_TYPE_ID (int, FK)

WidgetType
-----------
WIDGET_TYPE_ID (int, PK)
WIDGET_TYPE_NAME (varchar)
```

example Widget records:

```
WIDGET_ID | WIDGET_TYPE_ID (FK)
1           3
2           4
```

example WidgetType records:

```
WIDGET_TYPE_ID | WIDGET_TYPE_NAME 
3                "Foo"
4                "Bar"
```

Basically many tables in my DB have corresponding "Type" tables associated with them that I would like to construct as enumerations in the object model, ie:

```
Widget newWidget = new Widget();
newWidget.WidgetType = WidgetType.Foo;
```

Is there ANY way to do this with NHibernate, if so what would the mapping look like? If not, what's the best approximation? The only way I could think of was to construct a (not persisted) enumeration type in code that matches the type IDs:

```
enum WidgetType { Foo=3, Bar=4 };
```

But I'd rather not have to maintain this enum as things are added/removed from the DB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# enumerations are just a design-time convenience that exist to make code easier to read and write. They just compile to integers (or whatever the appropriate primitive type is).

To get NHibernate (or any other ORM) to manage them, you'd have to integrate it into the IDE and Visual Studio would have to interact with it *while you edit your code*. That might be useful, but I suspect you'd have to have a lot of enums that change fairly frequently for it to really be worth it.

There's no add-in like that for NHibernate that I'm aware of, but you can use a code generator to keep your enumerations in sync with your database tables (for example, the [Text Template Transformation Toolkit](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) - aka "T4 Templates" - which comes with Visual Studio).

Comment: So are you suggesting I write an SQL query to get the WIDGET_TYPE_IDs and WIDGET_TYPE_NAMEs and then use T4 to generate code for the enums? 

Seems overly complicated... I'd argue that NHibernate IS designed to do mapping from DB records to objects--being an ORM and all. If they don't have any nice Enum support, i'd rather just model them as standard classes (and be mildly dissapointed in NHibernate's lack of Enum support...)

Comment: @Jeff - exactly. Maybe I misunderstood your problem: you're absolutely right that standard classes work fine. Why do you want to use enumerations instead of standard classes in the first place?

Comment: Enums are a closer mapping to how I would treat the "Type" tables in object-land. If I mapped them as classes I'd have to do something like this:

WidgetType FooType = new WigetType;
FooType.Type = "Foo";

Widget widget = new Widget;
widget.WigetType = FooType;

(I'd also have to make sure that creating new instances of "Type" classes don't insert new records, but instead reference existing items by their string value)

basically it's more of a pain...

Comment: Fair enough, I can see why you want those semantics - I've updated my answer to try to clarify why we don't have such a thing.